How come "Updating Lights" takes forever in Blender?
Sorry, this is a repost but with a bit more information and pictures.
I'm trying to render an animation and everytime it says "Updating Lights" the entire render freezes. Roughly 50 seconds later it unfreezes, finishes rendering, and goes through the entire process again.
I have the Intel-i7 and NVIDIA rtx 3070. I am in cycles, gpu compute, with my light tree OFF. Average render time is usually around 6 seconds for any other project and now it's 62.
Here's the first part of the render. There are 5 words in this picture, all with keyframed emmission. The Earth was pulled from Blender kit.

The second part rotates down onto more keyframed emmision text, with a heart in the middle. I have 2 seperate area lights, one that shines on the Earth and the other that shines on the heart, also keyframed.

Sorry if I didn't include something this time around, and I will try to be as responsive as possible. Also, my background is a 16k starmap.
Edit: if there isn’t a fix for this, are there any substitutes that can get near the look I’m looking for? I basically want the text to fade in and out with the lyrics to this song, but as of now I only know how to do that by key framing emission and lights.

You could write an answer and mark it as solved. The only use is for posterity, for other people that may have the same issue. Otherwise you can let your question as is, it's up to you :)

Oh, that's quite an old classic (the song, not the problem). The edits where you come to a solution could be removed from the question, but since it is solved it doesn't really matter I guess.

I ended up minimizing all of the dropdowns in my render properties menu and enabled "Persistent Data" which fixed my problem. Render time dropped from around 60 seconds to 9 :).
